# Obtain a token from an AAD login

Tags: c#, sql, azure, azure-active-directory, token

Is it possible to authenticate with AAD, take that token and use it to authenticate with Azure SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's indeed possible. If you use Managed Identity, for instance in an Azure Function, this can look as simple as this:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;

var connection = new SqlConnection("Server=tcp:yourdbserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;")
connection.AccessToken = (new AzureServiceTokenProvider()).GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;
```

Comment: to give more context, I am running an MVC web app which is deployed on a virtual machine (on IIS). When the website is opened the user is prompted to log into Azure AD. This works. I then want the user to be able to authenticate to an Azure SQL database without having to log in again. I cannot use the PromptBehaviour method to bring up a dialog box, as the site is to be accessed by client machines (the dialog box will not show up on a client machine).

Comment: I got the following error when trying the above method:

Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProviderException: Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://database.windows.net/, Authority: . Exception Message: Tried the following 4 methods to get an access token, but none of them worked....